# How to Increment time by 15 minutes

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

In `MySql` database we have a column of type time and  we need to increment the time by fifteen minutes in our php code.

For example time is 09:45:00, it should become 10:00:00

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can fetch it directly from mysql itself:

```
Select DATE_ADD('09:45:00', INTERVAL 15 MINUTE) as updatetime from tableName
```

For more information you can visit : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

As per your comment if you want to do it in PHP, You can do like this:

```
$date = new DateTime('09:45:00');
$date->add(new DateInterval('PT15M'));
echo $date->format('h:i:s') . "\n";  //it i will give you 10:00:00
```

Comment: It's proper solution. Just was about to post it but you were faster :)

Comment: I think it's better to control every thing in php

Comment: Sir,
i want to retrieve the value from the database into a variable then increment and display the value.

Comment: @ashwinbhy: added php  code also.

Answer (score 3):

how about doing this:

```
strtotime("+15 minutes" , time());

strtotime("+15 minutes" , strtotime( $this->time )); // suppose it's a string
```

Comment: Which language has `strtotime()` *and* `now()`? Why the double timestamp → string → timestamp conversion?

Comment: you were right, wanting to write my answer as fast as I could :D ,btw php

Comment: PHP doesn't have `now()`.